# How to SET table data when the Primary Key "Submission_ID" and "TimeEntered" are auto incremented

Tags: php, mysql, insert, auto-increment

So I have a table that I am trying to insert data into from textboxes on a webpage. This table has two columns that are auto-incremented. These columns are the Primary key which is "Submission_ID" and the "TimeEntered" column. We are unsure what the query should be to SET the data to the table in the database. Here is the code:

```
include('connect-db.php');

//Setting Values of Textboxes to strings and making sure it's valid and secure
$SubmissionID = test;
$SchoolID= $_POST['newSchoolID'];
$UserID = $_POST['newUserID'];
$UndergradHead = $_POST['newUndergradHead'];
$UndergradFTE = $_POST['newUndergradFTE'];
$GradHead = $_POST['newGradHead'];
$GradFTE = $_POST['newGradFTE'];
$ProfessionalHead= $_POST['newProfessionalHead'];
$ProfessionalFTE = $_POST['newProfessionalFTE'];
$TimeEntered = Null;
$type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']));

 //Generating the Query
if($type == "ibhe")
{
    mysql_query("INSERT Count 
                    SET Submission_ID= NULL, 
                    School_ID='$SchoolID', 
                    UserID='$UserID', 
                    UnderCount='$UndergradHead', 
                    FTE_UnderCount='$UndergradFTE', 
                    GradCount='$GradHead', 
                    FTE_GradCount='$GradFTE', 
                    Pro_HeadCount='$ProfessionalHead', 
                    Pro_FT_Enrollment='$ProfessionalFTE, 
                    TimeEntered=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") 
                    or die(mysql_error());
 echo "Entry Added";
}
```

We were able to do this fine on a previous webpage where there was not any auto-incremented data being entered, but now we are unable to do the query since the two columns in the table are setup to auto-increment.

Comment: You had better show us your Schema so we can be sure what these 2 fields are set up as

Answer (score -1):

first of all if you have an column with auto_increment you can't declare that has a null value `Submission_ID= NULL` you have to be sure is it really needed to let submission id as auto_increment  and if so, simple don't call in the query, just lets be, and if not, then you have to detach the auto_increment property in the column and assign it manually.